# How do you add JS to an Elementor Custom Widget in preview mode when requiring dependancies

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am trying to create my own custom widget as a plugin in Elementor. I have the front end working but now the preview widget is broken. I get a nondescript error.

In my widget class file I register the JS like so :

```
 public function get_script_depends() {
    wp_register_script( 'double-carousel', plugins_url( 'double-carousel.js', __FILE__ ), [ 'elementor-frontend' ] );
    return [ 'double-carousel' ];
 }
```

However this breaks the preview page, if I remove the dependancy `elementor-frontend` then the preview screen works but the JS doesn't as it's added to early on the page (hence the dependancy). I tried to find a common dependancy but couldn't so I think i'm barking up the wrong tree. What am I missing?

Thanks

https://developers.elementor.com/add-javascript-to-elementor-widgets/#Registering_the_Widget_Handler_with_Elementor

Comment: Why not use `wp_enqueue_script` instead? I'm also surprised it works at all with the return statement - instead of `wp_enqueue_script('double-carousel')`. How are you calling your `get_script_depends()` method in your Class?

Comment: That is the Elementor way, the Elementor engine calls the method.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a solution. Don't enqueue the JS if we're in preview mode. Not ideal but better than a brick.

```
public function get_script_depends() {
    if ( \Elementor\Plugin::$instance->preview->is_preview_mode() ){
        return [];
    } else{
        wp_register_script( 'double-carousel', plugins_url( 'double-carousel.js', __FILE__ ), [ 'elementor-frontend' ] );
        return ['double-carousel' ];
    }
 }
```